# How to change the order and size of the labels in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, discrete

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDevI.png)

In this question, how to modify the default graph, named scalesGraph001 stored in R environment, to graph B? I tried many methods but failed to change the order and size of the 'flav' label.

I am totally not sure what command should I use. For instance, scale_color_manual, scale_fill_manual, or scale_y_discrete.

`

```
p <- scalesGraph001 +
scale_color_manual(name = "flav", breaks = c("c","r", "s", "v"),
labels = c("c", "s", "r", "v"), size = c(16,12,8,4))
print(p1)
```

`The first 10 rows of dataset:`

```
structure(list(flav = c("c", "v", "c", "c", "v", "v", "c", "v", 
"c", "c"), top = c("c", "s", "n", "s", "c", "c", "n", "n", "c", 
"c"), syr = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), weight = c(13.1, 14.4, 11.4, 8.7, 6.2, 
12.6, 5.1, 12.8, 10.9, 6.5), cal = c(1293.1, 1460.5, 1202.2, 
844.4, 552.9, 1259.4, 520.6, 1308.1, 1084.5, 649.8)), row.names 
= c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

`

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77379856/edit) with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is a placeholder for the name of your data set.)

Comment: I cannot figure out the graph so I did not post my code. Now I post my try out. The sample data cannot be given and I am sorry for that. Our professor only gives a graph like that. The data is very large.

Comment: I have added the code for the data set. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try adding `scale_size_manual(values = c(c=16,s=12,r=8,v=4))`.

Comment: Thank you, it works! What about the orders in the legends? I really have no idea how to change the order

Comment: To change the order of the labels, coerce `flav` to `factor` and set the `levels` argument to the order you want.